# Исходники .NET: GetTypes()

Tags: c#, .net

Всем добра!

Хотел посмотреть порядок, по которому [GetTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.module.gettypes(v=vs.110).aspx) выдает результат, в исходниках. Зашел, [смотрю](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/module.cs,43c51eba583941a2) и вижу:

```
    public virtual Type[] GetTypes()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

ээ... Что это значит?

Comment: Обрати внимание, что это [public **abstract** class Module](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/module.cs,68) и этот метод просто переопределяется в наследниках

Comment: @Grundy, да, верно. Но я тогда [не вижу нигде этого переопределения](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=GetTypes). Даже по `override Type[] GetTypes` пробовал искать

Comment: @Александр например: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/modulebuilder.cs,829

Comment: [раз](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/modulebuilder.cs,829), [два](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/module.cs,1116)

Comment: @tym32167, хм, это, конечно, наследники. Но они в пространстве имён Reflection.Emit, а не Reflection. То есть это не то. Но даже по вашей ссылке идёт внутри функции идёт вызов private GetTypes без тела, помеченный ключевым словом extern. Видимо, загружается с какой-то внешней dll в ресурсах и концов нет

Comment: Ваш вопрос был: `ээ... Что это значит?` - мой ответ- это значит, что метод реализован не в данном классе, а в наследниках. Если вы кликните на метод, то слева у вас [появятся наследники](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfuqM.png), где метод перегружен. Зачем он перегружен и как он должен работать я не имею понятия.